# /dev/ttyUSB0 not creating in Android

Tags: android, linux, driver, beagleboard

I am working with a custom ROM of Android with BeagleBone platform.My most challenging issue is /dev/ttyUSB0 is not generating for some Dongles of Huawei(E303C , E303F etc).But for some Huawei dongles /dev/ttyUSB0 is generated properly (E303D Huawei Idea & Almost locked dongles) . I have already tried with running "echo "12d1 1446ff" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id" as root.But nothing works.Somebody please help me to solve this critical issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the device drivers for some dongles in your kernel. You will need to check the kernel source code to be sure.

Comment: I am a greenhorn in in embedded android development.How can i check it .Is there any workaround ?

Comment: With the current mechanism of android kernel development there is no easy workaround. I would start looking online for guides about how to compile a kernel for your device. And continue from there